# Is electric potential inversely proportional to the voltage at a point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, potential

Consider this simple diagram, where the thermistor's resistance = $500\Omega$.

[image]
Let's suppose the temperature of the room increases. Then, Electric potential at point `A` should (apparently) increase

> The resistance of thermistor (and 750 Ω combination) decreases
> Therefore potential difference across thermistor and 750 Ω combination decreases
> Therefore potential at A increases

However, [Electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) is the amount of energy needed to bring a charge/particle from earth to that point.
In that case, it is similar to `Work` done in required to bring a charge from one point to another.
$$
W = VQ\:  \therefore W \propto V
$$
So as the potential difference across thermistor and $750\Omega$ **decreases**, the `Work` required to bring a particle to `A` *should* be lesser, which implies the Electric potential at that point to be actually reduced since less energy is required to bring any point from infinity to `A`

Can anyone explain this apparent contradiction?

Comment: You haven't defined an earth node in your circuit, so we can't define the potential as the energy needed to move a charge from earth to another point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, Electric potential is the amount of energy needed to bring a
> charge/particle from earth to that point.

The Wikipedia article states that the electrical potential is "the  amount of work energy needed to move a unit of electric charge from a reference point to the specifc point in an electric field".  Though the point chosen to be the zero potential reference point is arbitrary, it is logically selected to facilitate the analysis.

When evaluating potentials in an electric circuit the zero potential reference point is generally some point in the circuit, typically the negative terminal of a battery in the circuit. Once that point is set, then the potentials at other points are measured with respect to that point. But regardless of what point is chosen, the ***potential differences*** between points will be the same.

So if we choose the zero potential reference point to be the negative terminal of the battery in your circuit, then

1. The potential at the positive terminal of the battery is obviously 6V.
2. The potential at A is the potential at the positive terminal of the battery (6V) minus the potential drop across the parallel combination of the thermistor and 750 Ohm resistor.
3. If the thermistor resistance decreases, the equivalent parallel resistance of the thermistor and 750 Ohm resistor decreases. That equivalent parallel resistance and the 300 Ohm resistor form a voltage divider. A decrease in the equivalent parallel resistance results in a lower voltage drop across the parallel resistance and a greater drop across the 300 Ohm resistor.

Thus a decrease in the thermistor resistance results in an increase in the potential at A (the potential at A becomes closer to the potential of the positive battery terminal).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Electrical potential (like other potentials) is only defined to an arbitrary additive constant. You seem to be trying to compare potentials defined with different constants and getting confused.

> Electric potential is the amount of energy needed to bring a charge/particle from earth to that point.

This is one choice of additive constant. You can choose any point in your circuit as the "earth" or "ground" node, choosing the additive constant that makes the potential at that node 0. Then you can measure all other potentials in the circuit relative to that node.

But, you haven't actually defined which node in your circuit is the earth node. This is usually done by attaching the earth or ground symbol to one of the nodes in the circuit diagram. You could choose the anode of the battery, the cathode of the battery, or even node 'A', and you would still be able to use circuit analysis to predict the behavior of the circuit with equal validity.

> less energy is required to bring any point from infinity to A

This is another choice of additive constant. You can choose the "point at infinity" as the 0 potential reference point.

But you shouldn't assume that this choice will give you the same numerical values for the potentials in your circuit that choosing one of the circuit nodes as the reference point was.

In this problem, you don't have enough information to determine the potential of the circuit relative to infinity. You'd have to know the overall charge on the components of the circuit, and their physical arrangement in space, and whether any other charged objects exist in the universe around it to be able to do that. So this is not a useful choice for solving this problem.

**So, how do you actually solve the problem?**

You can actually solve this problem using Kirchoff's voltage law (KVL) without having to define a potential reference, or "ground", node.

I'll call the node at the battery cathode 'B' and the node at the anode 'C'.

Then KVL allows you to write the equation

$$V_{BA} + V_{AC} + V_{CB} = 0$$

where $V_{xy}$ represents the potential difference between node $x$ and node $y$, $V_x-V_y$.

Using what you know about the various circuit elements, and calling the current flowing counter-clockwise around the circuit $I$, we re-write our equation

$$-IR_{BA}-I(300\ \Omega) + 6\ V = 0$$

which can be rearranged to get

$$I = \frac{6\ V}{300\ \Omega+R_{BA}}.$$

Since $I(300\ \Omega)$ is the potential difference between node 'A' and the battery anode (what you were probably assuming should be used as the reference potential), we are interested in the quantity,

$$V_{AC} = I(300\ \Omega) = 6\ V \frac{300\ \Omega}{300\ \Omega+R_{BA}}$$

(you might recognize the voltage divider formula in this equation). This confirms the logic you quoted. As the resistance of the thermistor decreases, the denominator of our final expression decreases and the potential at 'A' increases.

Answer (score 0):

"So as the potential difference across thermistor decreases, the Work required to bring a particle to A should be lesser"

You're  confused.

Firstly, the potential difference across the thermistor is measured from point A to point B, if the potential difference from A to B is decreased, then the potential difference from B to A is increased ( as the line integrals are negative of eachother).

So in the case that the PD is decreased, (and therefore increased going the other direction), more work is required to bring a test charge from point B to point A.

Setting the zero of potential at point B, clearly shows the potential at A is increased.

If potential increases in one choice of reference, it increases in all choices of reference